# In custom class when calling a=s+b causing s (or b) also be effected (and even when declared as constant)

Tags: c++, class, struct, operator-overloading

So recently I'm working with my custom class which when I preform arithimetic operation it'll also effect the argument within the equation (so when called `auto a=s+b` will also caused `s` getting changed). Even when I declare those variables as `const` and pass arguments all with value (not reference).

So here's (part of) my classes' code:

```
template<typename T>
struct coord {
    T *d;
    long unsigned int dim;
    coord(di dim, T val=0.0): dim(dim) {
        d=new T[dim];
        for(di i=0;i<dim;i++) {
            d[i]=val;
        }
    }
    coord(initializer_list<T> l): dim{l.size()} {
        //d=(T *)calloc(dim, sizeof(T));
        d=new T[dim];
        copy(l.begin(), l.end(), d);
    }
    coord<T> operator+=(const coord<T> &r) {
        //for(int i=0; i<(r.dim<this->dim?r.dim:this->dim); i++) {
        if(r.dim>this->dim) {
            throw "Addition's rhs has larger Dimension than lhs.";
        }
        for(di i=0; i<r.dim; i++) { this->d[i]+=r[i]; }
        return *this;
    }
    T& operator[](int i) {
        return d[i];
    }
    T operator[](int i) const {
        return d[i];
    }
    friend coord<T> operator+(coord<T> lhs, const coord<T> &r) { return lhs+=r; }
};
```

And when I execute the following main code:

```
int main() {
    coord<double> s({3,2,3});
    coord<double> b({3,2,3});
    cout << s << endl;
    auto a=s+b;
    s+=b;
    cout << s << endl << b << endl << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the output:

```
3, 2, 3
3, 2, 3
9, 6, 9
9, 6, 9
```

Where the first one is the original `s`, and the others are respectively `s`, `b` and `a` after addition.

Then I think perhaps I've passed something as reference, so I go back to code and change everything to pass by value (only changing the + operation for now) to the following code:

```
coord<T> operator+=(coord<T> r) {
    //for(int i=0; i<(r.dim<this->dim?r.dim:this->dim); i++) {
    if(r.dim>this->dim) {
        throw "Addition's rhs has larger Dimension than lhs.";
    }
    for(di i=0; i<r.dim; i++) { r[i]+=this->d[i]; }
    return r;
}
friend coord<T> operator+(coord<T> lhs, const coord<T> r) { return lhs+=r; }
```

Which this time gave:

```
3, 2, 3
9, 6, 9
3, 2, 3
9, 6, 9
```

Which basiaclly we could assume that addition operation will effect the original variable. But that shouldn't happen as we're passing arguments  by value instead of reference, so why? And how could I solve it?

Comment: Look at rule of 5/3/0. Using `std::vector` would avoid the issue.

Comment: This sounds like an exercise in "find the undefined behavior". This is always easier when the code has been stripped down to the minimum needed to demonstrate the issue

Comment: One you get your rule-of-three woes out of the way, remember: when done correctly the cumulative member operators (ex: `operator +=`) should return a reference to `*this;`. value-result binary operators (ex: `operator +`) should return by value. In your posted code your free function `operator +` is correct; your member `operator +=` is *not*.

Comment: I don't understand this: "Which shows that s is also modified, despite I've set it to const. ". You haven't set `s` to `const` at all. It's defined as `coord<double> s` and later on it's obvious where it's modified: `s+=b;`. If `s` was really `const` then `s+=b` shouldn't compile.

Comment: @Jarod42 not using vector is due to the code also needs to be used at CUDA device, which doesn't support std::vector.

Comment: @TimRandall Oh, I've accidentally left old content in there. I 'm referring to += which despite b is passed as const it still got changed (which like you said, at compile time it should raise error and prevent it, yet it didn't)

Comment: `thrust::device_vector<class T>` seems to be the equivalent of `std::vector`, device's side.

Comment: You **CANNOT** write any C++ code without knowing the rule of 3/5/0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no copy constructor and/or copy assignment so when you copy the `coord<T>` only the pointer `d` will be copied, not the memory that `d` is pointing to. This could be solved either with a constructor/assignment or by using `std::vector` and letting the vector handle all the memory management for you as someone pointed out. Using `std::vector` comes with a bunch of other stuff that you dont need though (for example of the dimensions of a coord never change). A simple constructor and copy assignment like the one below is just fine.

```cpp
coord(const coord<T> &other) : dim(other.dim) {
    d = (T *)malloc(dim * sizeof(T));
    memcpy(d, other.d, dim * sizeof(T));
}

coord<T> &operator=(const coord<T> &other) {
    free(d);
    dim = other.dim;
    d = (T *)malloc(dim * sizeof(T));
    memcpy(d, other.d, dim * sizeof(T));
}
```